# Ansible stops service but doesn't restart it

Tags: ansible

We recently deployed Ansible in our different environments and I'm running into a problem I can't find a solution to.

On two servers you have to start and stop the services by becoming a specific user.

```
su - itvmgr
```

Then you have to run a custom command to stop and start the services:

```
itvmgrctl stop dispatcher
itvmgrctl start dispatcher
```

One of the tasks looks like this:

```
- name: "Start Dispatcher Service"
  sudo_user: itvmgr
  command: su itvmgr -c '/itvmgr/bin/itvmgrctl start dispatcher'

- name: Pause
  pause: seconds=15
```

There's another task to stop it which looks just like this one just using `stop` instead of `start`.

The problem I'm running into is Ansible stops the service fine but it fails to start the service again. I'm not getting any errors while it's running but I can't find any reason why it would stop the service fine, but the same command fails to start it.

If anyone has any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the results of the `ansible-playbook` command you're running with `-v` for verbose output?

Comment: The output is to long to post, so I'll post a link to a text file below that has the output.

Comment: https://nexus1.net-collective.net/owncloud/index.php/s/GarQYuA16u0yMLa

Comment: Is there anything in the itvmgrctl logs?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you start-script needs an interactive shell or some environment variables?